# Is it possible to recover the package/program "Screen Configuration" in Buster

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, packages

I removed Python 2.7 and some packages attached to it by mistake, I've to reinstall the desktop and other utilities, but I couldn't figure out how with this one.
Only way to change screen resolution by now is editing config.text,( raspi-config doesn't work and screen option in Raspberry Pi Configuration doesn't exist) since I work with my Pi in several monitors, it's tedious to change this way.
So, I wish to know if there's a command to get back the packages built-in in a fresh installation, or "Screen Configuration" has a name to be installed?, considering I don't want to reflash

Comment: Try installing the package `arandr`. Use e.g. `sudo apt update && sudo apt install arandr`

Comment: How did you access this Screen Configuration package before? I can't seem to find it on my Pi (running the latest Raspbian Buster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Screen Configuration with `sudo apt install -y arandr`.

What you really want to do is see what you uninstalled. Easy: This command shows you what is in the apt-get log file:

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log
```

Still missing something? You can quickly compare what your desktop looks like vs default Raspbian using my [vdesktop tool](https://bitly.com/2GeNuIw). Essentially it boots any Raspbian .img file and then connects to it like a remote desktop.
Here's a screenshot of me running Stretch inside Buster.[image: Running both Stretch and Buster on the same Pi[2]]
Of course, you want to run a Buster img with vdesktop. These commands will do that for you:

```
git clone https://github.com/Botspot/vdesktop
chmod +x /home/pi/vdesktop/vdesktop
wget https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2019-09-30/2019-09-26- 
raspbian-buster.zip
unzip /home/pi/2019-09-26-raspbian-buster.zip
sudo /home/pi/vdesktop/vdesktop /home/pi/2019-09-26-raspbian-buster.zip
```